# Error al mostrar un hashmap en un Jlist Java

Tags: java

Estoy con un ejercicio de clase en el cual tengo que mostrar los elementos de un `arraylist` que está dentro de un fichero. pero me da excepción de **nullpointer** en la linea que está escrito `titulo_y_autor = libro.getTitulo() + " | " + libro.getAutor();`

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at biblioteca.Metodos.verColeccion(Metodos.java:107)    at
>   biblioteca.BibliotecaPrincipal.btnListarActionPerformed(BibliotecaPrincipal.java:670)

```
 public static JList verColeccion(HashMap biblio,File fichero) {

        DefaultListModel<String> modeloLista = new DefaultListModel<>();
        JList lista = new JList(modeloLista);
        String titulo_y_autor;

        Iterator iterador_biblioteca = biblio.entrySet().iterator();

        while (iterador_biblioteca.hasNext()) {
            Libros libro = new Libros();
            libro = (Libros) biblio.get(iterador_biblioteca.next());
            titulo_y_autor = libro.getTitulo() + " | " + libro.getAutor();
            modeloLista.addElement(titulo_y_autor);
        }
    return lista;
    }
```

Comment: No entiendo tu código, ¿al crear `biblio` no lo llenaste con objetos del tipo `Libros`? ¿Por qué entonces esto: `Libros libro = new Libros();` y luego esto: `libro = (Libros) biblio.get(iterador_biblioteca.next());`? ¿Podrías mostrar cómo está constituido tu `HashMap` y dar más detalles de lo que quieres hacer? Da la impresión de que aplicas una lógica inversa en tu código.

Comment: Si, tiene datos de la clase libros ya metidos. Entiendo que crear objeto Libros otra vez es ilógico. Lo que pretendo hacer es listar en un Jlist los libros que hay metidos en el Hahsmap

Comment: Tu problema existe porque no usas bien los genericos de Java. Tus tipos son ambiguos, así apuesto que tu HashMap no es un HashMap<Map.Entry, Object>, sin embargo usas un Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> y luego buscas con los Entry como key en el HashMap. Define los tipos como corresponde y vas a encontrar tu error.

Answer (score 0):

Ni siquiera necesitas un iterador para lo que quieres hacer.

Si `biblio` es un `HashMap` con objetos del tipo `Libros`, puedes hacer simplemente esto:

```
for (Libros libro : biblio.values()) {
    titulo_y_autor = libro.getTitulo() + " | " + libro.getAutor();
    modeloLista.addElement(titulo_y_autor);
}
```

Comment: Creo que su problema viene porque tiene guardado en su HashMap un objeto a null. Con esto seguiría dando el mismo problema.